# Instrumenting JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I would like to instrument JavaScript code in order to "log" values of global variables. For example I would like to know all the values a particular variables *foo* had during execution. The logging is not the problem.

What would be the easiest way to implement this? I was thinking of using [Rhino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_%28JavaScript_engine%29) (the JavaScript implementation in Java created by Mozilla) to generate an [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) and modifying this AST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the cvshead version of Rhino, I instrumented the code.

Comment: could you share some code of the basics of the way you did it?

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you are looking for:

http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/

Put a log in the setter and that's it. Of course, I do not know where does this actually work, if it must be trusted code, or any web page, or what.

Based on John Resig's code, I would add to my debug code something like:

```
var placeLoggerInSetter = function(variableName, obj){ //obj may be window
    obj.__defineSetter__(variableName, function(val){
         console.log(val); //log whatever here
         obj[variableName] = val;
    });
}

var something = 0;
placeLoggerInSetter("something", window);
something = 1;
//out goes "1" in the console
something = 2
//out goes "2" in the console
```

Is that more like it? Again, I did not test it and the `obj[variableName]` line looks quite recursive to me... will you tell here if it works? :)

Also, with [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug),

```
console.dir(obj)
```

will let you see all the properties of that object in the console, instead of converting it to string as with `log()`. And also expand the properties and so on. Handy.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But the real question is, how to insert this code automatically?

Comment: I'll edit this answer with a (totally untested) function to do what I think you want (and which would be, by the way, a totally sweet feature for firebug!)

Comment: If you meant to add this automatically to every variable and every property.... are you sure???

Comment: The code sample doesn't seem to work, "too much recursion". The setter keeps calling the setter or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not restricted to Rhino/Java, the Johnson Ruby gem integrates the Spidermonkey/Tracemonkey interpreter into Ruby. It does provide access to the AST. I haven't tried modifying the AST; not sure if that's possible (it might be, judging from the names in the code at looked at).

The Johnson gem is in jbarnette's Johnson repo at github. (Switch id's; Stackoverflow doesn't want me to put links in at this point ...) I added tracemonkey support recently and it's not yet integrated into the master source. It's in my (smparkes)'s Johnson repo at github.

Comment: Thanks! Sadly, Ruby is not an option :(

Answer (score 0):

Firebug (plugin for firefox) has a logging feature, to which you can write to a console. Much better than using alert("foo"); for everything

example log statement:

```
console.log("foo="+foo);
```

See [this post](http://michaelsync.net/2007/09/09/firebug-tutorial-logging-profiling-and-commandline-part-i) for more info (including more advanced usage)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not asking how to log stuff, I'm asking how to instrument Javascript code (to add logging automatically after each variable assignment for instance).

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea for a generic solution or anything that exists, but simply wrap those variables around a logging class that deals with get/sets and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dtrace:

http://opensolaris.org/os/project/mozilla-dtrace/

Answer (score 0):

You can set debugger; as first thing on the document ready event and just step through your code step by step.

..fredrik